# How to replace incorrect dates by using data from a different column in R

Tags: r, date, data-cleaning

I have a large medical dataset that I am cleaning. Some of the dates for operations are certainly improbable (a century before the date of admission!). Below is an example df:

```
doa = c("2010-08-01", "2010-08-07", "2008-09-01") # date of admission
doo_1 = c("2010-08-02", "1900-01-01", "2008-09-03") # date of first op
doo_2 = c("1800-01-01", "1900-01-01", "2008-09-03") # date of second op
df= data.frame (doa, doo_1, doo_2)
```

I want to replace the values in columns 2 and 3 (in real dataset there are 25 columns) when it is less than doa with doa+1 (as operations tend to happen day following admission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has requested to replace improbable dates of operations by `doa + 1` (next day after admission).

*If* this simple rule is to be applied to all 25 columns it is *not* necessary to reshape the dataset from wide to long format and back to wide format again.

```
library(data.table)

# coerce date columns from factor or character to IDate
date_cols <- c("doa", "doo_1", "doo_2")
setDT(df)[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = date_cols][]
# replace dates if improbable
df[doo_1 < doa, doo_1 := doa + 1L][]
df[doo_2 < doa, doo_2 := doa + 1L][]
```

> ```
>           doa      doo_1      doo_2
> 1: 2010-08-01 2010-08-02 2010-08-02
> 2: 2010-08-07 2010-08-08 2010-08-08
> 3: 2008-09-01 2008-09-03 2008-09-03
> ```

The OP has mentioned that the production datasets contains 25 columns. This requires a more flexible solution where the column names to work on are not hardcoded but are supplied in a vector:

```
op_cols <- c("doo_1", "doo_2")
for (x in op_cols) {
  df[get(x) < doa, (x) := doa + 1L]
}
df[]
```

Note that data.table updates by reference, i.e., without copying the whole data object but only the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

With data.table : you first create a patient number variable ptn

```
DT <- setDT(df)
setnames(DT,"doa","doo")
DT[,ptn := .I]
```

Then you melt your data

```
plouf <- melt(DT,measure.vars = patterns("^doo"))
plouf[,value:= as.Date(value)]
plouf[,.SD,by = ptn]
   ptn variable      value
1:   1      doo 2010-08-01
2:   1    doo_1 2010-08-02
3:   1    doo_2 1800-01-01
4:   2      doo 2010-08-07
5:   2    doo_1 1900-01-01
6:   2    doo_2 1900-01-01
7:   3      doo 2008-09-01
8:   3    doo_1 2008-09-03
9:   3    doo_2 2008-09-03
```

You then calculate the diff between each operation and the entry date for each patient (the ´by = ptn´ grouping operation allows that, and you know because of the naming that your doa is the first of each group)

```
plouf[,diff := value - value[1],by = ptn]
```

And if the difference is negative, you set the date to the entry date + 1

```
plouf[diff <0,value := value[1]+1,by = ptn]
```

Then you reshape the data to the initial shape

```
dcast(plouf, ptn ~variable )

   ptn        doo      doo_1      doo_2
1:   1 2010-08-01 2010-08-02 1800-01-02
2:   2 2010-08-07 1900-01-02 1900-01-02
3:   3 2008-09-01 2008-09-03 2008-09-03
```

I would though suggest that you replace the strange date by the last opertion +1 instead of the entry of patient. You can do as following

```
plouf[diff <0,value := as.Date(NA),by = ptn] # create NA to use locf
library(zoo)
plouf[,value := na.locf(value), by = ptn] # use locf
plouf[diff<0, value := value +1] # add one day
dcast(plouf, ptn ~variable )

   ptn        doo      doo_1      doo_2
1:   1 2010-08-01 2010-08-02 2010-08-03
2:   2 2010-08-07 2010-08-08 2010-08-08
3:   3 2008-09-01 2008-09-03 2008-09-03
```